# Position 3 images at the bottom of the div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using Bootstrap and trying to position these 3 images at the bottom without any success. Could you help?

[**JSFIDDEL**](https://jsfiddle.net/e46fp5kt/)

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <img src="https://s10.postimg.org/730mt4y5l/image.jpg" class="img-responsive first">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-8">
  <img src="https://s10.postimg.org/yp3edthih/image.jpg" class="img-responsive second">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <img src="https://s10.postimg.org/z4j9kkstl/image.jpg" class="img-responsive third">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.first {

}
.second {

}
.third {

}
```

The 3 images are of different dimensions. I would like to position them in such a way that all the images seat on the red border line.

Comment: I don't see the reason to reopen this. The solution is explained in other answers. http://www.codeply.com/go/fw3b4XJ3Pj

Comment: The main issue is making columns the same height

Answer (score 0):

For now, I only see to regulate with margin_top or padding_top, and responsive regulate with media switch.

```
style='margin_top:150px;'
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I have tried that. Thanks though.